# How can I add tls callback functions with gcc?

Tags: c, windows, gcc, mingw, thread-local-storage

I'm trying to add a tls callback function that change the value of a variable. I tried things that I saw in google like:

```
static int a = 0;

void NTAPI tls_callback(void* DllHandle, DWORD Reason, void* Reserved)
{
    a = 1;
}

#pragma comment (linker, "/INCLUDE:__tls_used")
#pragma comment (linker, "/INCLUDE:__xl_b")

#pragma data_seg(".CRT$XLB")
EXTERN_C PIMAGE_TLS_CALLBACK _xl_b = tls_callback;
#pragma data_seg()

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

but nothing work. When I run the program I get 0 as output instead 1. I'm using MinGW windows. I looked on IDA and I can see the function there:
[the function in IDA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOD8w.png)
but when I run the program I get the wrong output. I tried to debug the program in x96dbg but I don't see that the function executed. Is that because there are already callbacks by default when I compile with MinGW? What can I do?

Comment: A quick search finds this - https://developpaper.com/manual-addition-of-tls-callback-function/. Does it not help?

Comment: @nevilad I want it to be automatic. It's hard if every time that I change the exe I will have to change this either. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Create a tool that runs after the image is built and automate these steps. The hardest thing will be to automatically find your tls_callback address, but that's possible when you build with debug info.

Comment: @nevilad Can you give me a way to solve the tls_callback address problam? It will helps me a lot :)

Comment: You can run objdump on your binary, find the string with tls_callback and it's address, and create a script that will do the same automatic.

Answer (score 1):

CRT allows the program to register TLS Callbacks.

The Callbacks to execute are found in a NULL terminated Array.

A cariable of type PIMAGE_TLS_CALLBACK pointing to the callback must be declared in the CRT to register it in this array.

The compiler can concatenate into one section using the $ symbol.

The CRT section makes use of a specific naming convention; .CRT$XLx where x can be anything between A-Z. A is the beinning, Z is the null terminator.

All XLx are concatenated into the .CRT section.

Concatenation is done alphabetically, so the callback in .CRT$XLB will be called before .CRT$XLC.

custom callback function from https://github.com/Reijaff/offensive_c/blob/main/tls_callback.c :

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// tls area
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#if defined(_MSC_VER)
#define _CRTALLOC(x) __declspec(allocate(x))
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
#define _CRTALLOC(x) __attribute__((section(x)))
#else
#error Your compiler is not supported.
#endif

static void WINAPI tls_callback(HANDLE hDllHandle, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID __UNUSED_PARAM(lpReserved))
{
    switch (dwReason)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        printf("attach\n");
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        printf("detach\n");
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        printf("thread attach\n");
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        printf("thread detach\n");
        break;
    }
}

// tlsinit function executes functions allocated in subsections in alphabetical order from xd_a to xd_z
// every function need to be allocated separately with it's own letter
//
// ps = (uintptr_t) &__xd_a;
// ps += sizeof (uintptr_t);
// for ( ; ps != (uintptr_t) &__xd_z; ps += sizeof (uintptr_t))
//
// from https://github.com/mirror/mingw-w64/blob/cb37f01f9cb54ccb85ed9c03086e6c4d84b5b431/mingw-w64-crt/crt/tlssup.c

_CRTALLOC(".CRT$XLF")
PIMAGE_TLS_CALLBACK __xl_f = tls_callback;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```